# Dual of the given LP

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am trying to find the dual of a LP.  So far I am stuck, can anyone help me please ?.

$$
\max_{x} \sum_{i=0}^{K-1} a_ix_i\\
\text{subject to} \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} x_i \leq t\;, t = 1\dots K\\
x_i \geq 0
$$

So far, I do not find a way to represent the first constraint in a vector / matrix form.  If someone can point me a way to represent the first constraint in vectot/matrix form, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ denote the column-vector $a = (a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{K-1})$, and let $x$ denote the column-vector $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{K-1})$.  Take
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1&0&\cdots & 0\\
1&1 & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & & \ddots & 0\\
1 & &  \cdots   & 1
}, \qquad b = \pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ K}
$$
We can then restate the LP as
$$
\text{maximize (over $x$) } \quad a^Tx\\
\text{subject to } \quad Ax \leq b, \quad x \geq 0
$$